# Can't log in to mysql server. (Error 1045)

Tags: mysql, phpmyadmin

I added a new user using phpmyadmin, and I get an error, and I used SQL Query :

```
create database foo_db;
create user foo_user identified by 'foo_password';
grant all on foo_db.* to 'foo_user'@'%';
flush privileges;
```

but It dosen't works too.

the error messeges was

```
ERROR 1045 (28000): Access denied for user 'folderfile'@'localhost' (using password: YES) (mysql) 
#1045 Cannot log in to the MySQL server (phpmyadmin)
```

I can't solve this problem, please help.

Comment: You created user `foo_user` but tried to login as `folderfile`

Answer (score 2):

Try this:

```
CREATE USER 'testtt'@'localhost' IDENTIFIED BY '***';

GRANT ALL PRIVILEGES ON * . * TO 'testtt'@'localhost' IDENTIFIED BY '***' WITH
 GRANT OPTION MAX_QUERIES_PER_HOUR 0 MAX_CONNECTIONS_PER_HOUR 0 MAX_UPDATES_PER_HOUR 0
 MAX_USER_CONNECTIONS 0 ;

GRANT ALL PRIVILEGES ON `test` . * TO 'testtt'@'localhost';
```

Comment: @GeunhongKim - glad it did :)

Answer (score 0):

Can you login as root user?
if so, please try:

1、login as root user:
    mysql -u root

2、use mysql

3、update user set password=NEWPASSWORD where user='folderfile' and host='localhost' ;

4 FLUSH PRIVILEGES;

Good luck!!

Answer (score 0):

the problem is you haven't mentioned the host name while creating user

so try this to log into mysql

```
 mysql -u foo_user -h localhost -p
 Enter password: foo_password
```

it works no need to do any changes